# How to check programmatically if (apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services') added

Tags: android, gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm working on a library module using `FirebaseMessagingService`.

I need to add a check **if** `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` **is added in application module or not.**

What's the best approach to add that check and revoke compilation if that is not added.

If that's not possible then Is there any way to check programmatically in **Runtime** environment?

I tried to add something like this

```
if (pluginManager.hasPlugin('com.google.gms.google-services')) {
    println "Project $it.name: google plugin applied"
} else {
    println "no com.google.gms.google-services plugin applied"
}
```

but this condition never return **true.**

Comment: You want to check if user have google play services installed on their device?

Comment: I want to check if developer applied `com.google.gms.google-services` in his app or not